# Apply image as background in Drupal

Tags: drupal, twig

I created a template for a module and want to print to put an image as a background.

If I do,

```
{{content.field_background_image}}
```

I see the image path: /sites/default/files/2019-09/carrots-1082251_1280.jpg

But If I try it inside the HTML, the page breaks when I refresh it:

```
<div class="slide-content-wrapper" style="background-image: url('/{{ content.field_background_image }}')">
```

How can I put the content image as a background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very difficult time figuring this out initially as well. Here is what you can do:

1. Go to the 'Manage Display' for the content type your template is for.
2. Ensure that the Format on the image field is set to 'URL to image' and not 'Image'
3. Then write the following code in your template:

```html
<div style="background-image: url({{ content.field_background_image['0']['#markup'] }})">
```

When you insert {{ content.field_background_image }} it has a whole bunch of properties and values on it, so you have to access the specific field where the url to the image is located.

Comment: Support much appreciated @Soren Baird